# Check how many days were passed since the last update in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to check how many days were passed since the user last entered the system. I get the last time he\she entered from mysql table column (datetime). so I wrote :

```
$user_last_visit = $user_info['last_updated']; // 2013-08-08 00:00:00

$user_last_visit_str = strtotime($user_last_visit); // 1375912800
$today = strtotime(date('j-m-y')); // 1250114400

$diff = $today - $user_last_visit_str;
```

- Where `$user_info['last_updated']` has the last time he\she visited with the value of 2013-08-08 00:00:00.
- After strtotime I get `$user_last_visit_str` equals to 1375912800
- `$today` has the value of 9-08-13 and after strtotime  I get 1250114400.

Some reason `$diff = $today - $user_last_visit_str;` is negative instead of getting a positive value with `24*60*60*1000` (one day = `24*60*60*1000` ms).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php):

```
echo date_create()->diff(date_create($user_last_visit))->days;
```

If all else fails, just do:

```
$diff = floor((time() - $user_last_visit_str) / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: can you explain about the time formats and why it didn't work for me ?

Comment: I've tested the date and time you provided in your question and it works for me: `echo date_create()->diff(date_create('2013-08-07 00:00:00'))->days;` prints 2 for me, and 2013-08-08 prints 1. If you're using a different format that isn't being accepted by this function, then you can specify the format you're using with the [date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function. If you'd like to format the date interval with more information such as the number of years, months, days, hours, etc. then you can use the date_format function.

Comment: ink.attendant.6 has an example of the aforementioned functions in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140766/check-how-many-days-were-passed-since-the-last-update-in-php/18140952#18140952).

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to get date diff, here i given static last date which is 15th july 2013, and taking different from current date.

```
    $last_date = date('y-m-d', strtotime('15th july 2013'));//here give your date as i mentioned below
    //$last_date = date('y-m-d', strtotime($your_old_date_val));
$current_date = date('y-m-d');//

echo $date_diff = strtotime($current_date) -  strtotime($last_date) ;
echo $val = 60*60*24;
$days_diff = $date_diff / $val;

echo $days_diff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user_last_visit = $user_info['last_updated']; // considering the value of user last visit is 2013-08-08 00:00:00 which indicates year, month, day, hour, minute, second respectiveliy
$user_last_visit_str = strtotime($user_last_visit);
$today = time();

$diff = $today - $user_last_visit_str;
$no_of_days = ($diff / (60*60*24));
```

Comment: need to add floor($diff / (60*60*24))

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object if your version of PHP supports it:

```
$user_last_visit = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_info['last_updated']);
$today = new DateTime();
$diff = $today->diff( $user_last_visit, true );

echo $diff->days;
```

`$diff` will be a [`DateInterval`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object.

Answer (score 0):

try reversing the $today assignment, like so:

```
$today = strtotime(date('y-m-j'));
```

that worked for me.

Comment: why reversing the assignment worked ? because the $user_last_visit = $user_info['last_updated']; // 2013-08-08 00:00:00 has the year first ?